# How to make a div expand vertically to wrap the content within it?

Tags: css

I have a div which wraps a number of images that are generated dynamically. I don't know how high the list of images is. My problem is the div that contains the dynamically generated images doesn't behave like it is housing any content - I want it to extend to the height of the list of images. Each image is itself wrapped in a div.

This is the wrapper div:

```
.block { padding:10px; margin-top:10px; height:auto; background-color:#f9f9f9; }
```

This is the markup dynamically generated for (one of) the images:

```
<div class="block">
<div style="float: left; padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;"><IMG SRC="45.jpg" BORDER="0"/></div>
.....
```

How do I get the `block` div to extend down with the images?

Thanks

Comment: How are you adding images dynamically, using appendChild ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The problem you're observing happens when you float an element, which takes it out of the normal flow of the elements (by normal flow I mean the way the elements would appear with no styling).  When you float an element, the other elements still in the normal flow will simply ignore it and do not make room for it, which is why your `block` div does not extend the full height of your image.

There are a few different solutions:

1) Add the rule `overflow: hidden;` to the `block` class:

```
.block { overflow: hidden; padding:10px; margin-top:10px; height:auto; background-color:#f9f9f9; }
```

2) Add a element after your image that clears the floating:

```
<div class="block">
    <div style="float: left; padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;"><IMG SRC="images/login1.png" BORDER="0"/></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Both will work, but I prefer the first solution.

Comment: Just came across this fix, and works perfectly @wsanville. That being the first option. Thanks, voted

Comment: It makes no sense, why does overflow hidden make the block expand to the necessary height instead of hiding the overflowing divs?

Answer (score 11):

REMOVE `float:left` from Image style  and `height:Auto` from block style

ADD `display:inline-block;` in block style (container style)

Comment: Awesome Otto. This is the only thing that worked for me with an article tag container that wouldn't expand even with a clearing div.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I got the wrapper element to wrap the content by setting the wrapper element's display to "table". So for your situation try

```
.block {padding:10px; margin-top:10px; height:auto; background- color:#f9f9f9; display: table;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your css:

```
.block::after{
    content : '';
    clear : both;
    display : block;
}
```

It will solve your problem.

It just inserts a blank "after" the block class.

Comment: I liked this solution initially, but maybe it is best to keep content out of the CSS? So I ended up with adding an empty div as per @wsanville answer, option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your CSS file:

```
.group:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; } .group {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/ * html .group {height: 1%;} .group {display: block;} /* End hide from IE-mac */
```

And add the "`group`" class to your `block` div so the float is cleared:

```
<div class="block group">
...
```

Answer (score -2):

I have a div tag that expands (horizontally and vertically) depending what I have in it. I have:

```
<div id="summary" style="float:right;margin:5px 5px 0;" ALIGN="right">
```

I also put a table within it to hold all my information:

```
<table style="margin-left:1em; border:2px solid #000000; background-color:#f2f2f2; padding:1px; float:center; clear:right; font-size:85%;">
```

Comment: There is no "center" value for the "float" property.